# Is it good idea to help OP to add the question sentence if the OP doesn't state their questions directly?

Tags: discussion, questions

Sometimes I can see questions that OP states the problem in plain description instead of a question sentence like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399268), or the problem is clear if you get the idea like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411006). Unfortunately they are closed and I think the reason is they're not asking questions directly.

My question is, is it a good idea to help them to add a question sentence  to describe the problem more directly so that it can help future visitors and even OP to reopen the questions?

Comment: For those particular questions, having an actual "question sentence" would not have helped them one bit. They were closed due to their other problems.